# Querying Entire JSON field data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to check on a way to query entire `json` field data in PostgreSQL. But, all I see is querying for a specific field like below.

```
# SAMPLE DATA
# data = {"test": 1, "test_another": 2}

select * from sample_table where data->>'test' = ('1')
```

The above condition yields the correct result. But, I have tried querying on the entire block in multiple ways, but, it dosent seem to work and returns below error.

```
select * from sample_table where data->'{"test": 1, "test_another": 2}'

#ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the contains operator `@>`

```
select * 
from sample_table 
where data @> '{"test": 1, "test_another": 2}'
```

or if you need an exact match:

```
select * 
from sample_table 
where data = '{"test": 1, "test_another": 2}';
```

The above requires `data` to be defined as `jsonb` (which it should be anyway). If it's only a `json` you need to cast it:

```
where data::jsonb = '{"test": 1, "test_another": 2}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately my column is defined as `json` and not as `jsonb`

Comment: Then you have to cast it:  `where data::jsonb = ...`

Comment: Works. Perfect!